# PHP display current server path

Tags: php

I need to setup a path in my php but I currently don't know the path.

I need to configure the paths to the uploads directory

Should look like this below:

```
/srv/www/uploads/
```

My uploads.php file is in the root...so

```
www/uploads/ ???
```

Is there anyway that I could get php to tell me my current path?

Comment: php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you call [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) it should give you the path:

```
<?php
  echo getcwd();
?>
```

Answer (score 18):

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 17):

- To get your current working directory: `getcwd()` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php))
- To get the document root directory: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))
- To get the filename of the current script: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following alternative [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.realpath.php).

**Create a file** called *path.php*

**Put the following code** inside by specifying the name of the created file.

```
<?php 
    echo realpath('path.php'); 
?>
```

A php file that you can move to all your folders to always have the absolute path from where the executed file is located.

;-)

Answer (score 2):

php can call command line operations so

```
echo exec("pwd");
```

Comment: I didn't realise `getcwd()` existed, it's probably better to use that.

Comment: Using command line operations like `exec` or `system` could be seen as a bad habit, it can lead to significant vulnerabilities.